# Compass bearing doesn't update on Google Map V2

Tags: android, google-maps, compass, heading

I want to have a smooth compass rotating in GoogleMap. I have created default GoogleMap project using Android Studio. I add the following to enable location and compass.

```
map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
```

But the compass doesn't update smoothly; updates once after about 10 seconds.
Can you tell me how to fix this?

Comment: is it in a fragment? can you show the full code?